# Why wont file data save to structure?

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct, malloc

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I have a program that successfully reads in data from a file. Once it does this the data that was read in SHOULD be able to be searched/shown/or deleted, but it does not do this. I know the file is being successfully read because when I add a `printf()` to the function reading the file, it prints out the correct data. Help would be wonderful. Here is the stripped down version of the code.

```
typedef struct friends_contact{

  char *First_Name;
  char *Last_Name;
  char *home;
  char *cell;
}fr;


int main() 
{
  fr friends[5];
  char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
  int counter=0;
  int i=0;

  menu(friends, &counter,i,buffer);

  getch();
  return 0;
}
//Menu function
void menu(fr*friends,int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) 
{
 int user_entry=0;
 int user_entry1=0;
 int user_entry2=0;
 char user_entry3[50]={'\0'};
 FILE *read;
 printf("Welcome! Would you like to import a file? (1)Yes or (2) No");
 scanf("%d",&user_entry1);
 if(user_entry1==1)
   {
    printf("Please enter a file name");
    scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
    read=fopen(user_entry3,"r");
   }else;

 do{
  int result;

  printf("\nPhone Book Application\n");
  printf("1) Add friend\n2) Delete friend\n3) Show a friend\n4) Show  phonebook\n5)Exit\n");   
  scanf("%d", &user_entry);
if(user_entry==1)
  {
    add_contact(friends,counter,i,buffer);
  }
if(user_entry==2)
  {
    delete_contact(friends ,counter,i);
  } 
if(user_entry==3)
  {
    result=show_contact(friends ,counter,i);
    if(result==0){
                  printf("\nName not Found\n");
                  }else{
                        result;
                        }

 }                  
if(user_entry==4)
 {
   print_contact(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
   if(user_entry1==1)
     {
   file2(friends ,counter,i,buffer,read);
      }else;
 } 

}while(user_entry!=5);


 }
```

The delete function

```
//This is used to delete a name out of the book
char delete_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i)
{
   char name_search[50]={'\0'};
   char Delete[5]={'\0'};

   printf("Search by last name\n");
   scanf("%s",name_search);//Name entry
   for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
      {
       if(strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)//Copys over the name entered
         {                                       
          strcpy(friends[i].Last_Name,Delete);
         }
       }
    //Freeing up memory.
    free(friends[i].First_Name);
    free(friends[i].Last_Name);
    free(friends[i].home);
    free(friends[i].cell);   

    printf("\nName(s) has been deleted\n");             
}
```

the print function:

```
//This function prints out all the contact information
void print_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]) 
{
    for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
    if (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name)&&        strlen(friends[i].home)&& strlen(friends[i].cell ))
       {

          getFirst(friends, i);
          getLast(friends, i);
          getHome(friends, i);
          getCell(friends, i);
        }
}
//Displays the contact in which you are searching for.
int show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i) 
{  
   char name_search2[50]={'\0'};
   int flag=0;
   printf("Please enter a last name\n");
   scanf("%s",name_search2);
   for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
      {
      //If the name is found, it reaturns the contact info.Now works for duplicate last names.
        if(strcmp(name_search2,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)
          {
             (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name)&& strlen(friends[i].home)&& strlen(friends[i].cell ));

            getFirst(friends, i);
            getLast(friends, i);
            getHome(friends, i);
            getCell(friends, i);
            flag++;
          }
     }         


    return flag;
}
```

The Read in function:

```
void file2(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char buffer[],FILE*read)
{
  fseek(read, 0, SEEK_SET); 

  while (fscanf(read,"%s", buffer) != EOF) 
     {
       friends[*counter].Last_Name=malloc(BUFFSIZE*strlen(buffer));

       strcpy(friends[*counter].Last_Name, buffer);

       printf("%s\n",friends[*counter].Last_Name);

      }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could shrink the program down to the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem (rather than making us read all of your code).  Note that is also a generally useful debugging technique; as you reduce your code in size, the cause of the problem may become evident.

Comment: The only reason I posted the entire thing was because I figured if I just posted the `main` and the read in file, that would be too little to do anything with...but I can edit down for you if that helps.

Comment: "it does not do this" well what does it do exactly ? what do you expect it to do ? and learn to use a `switch`

Comment: @jdigital The code has been stripped down.

Comment: @mux well it does nothing, unless of course I add a print statement to it, then it will print the data in the file. When I am not reading a file into the program, I can add names to the contacts list, this saves the names to the structures and allows for me to search the structure for those names or delete those names. I expect that when I read the file into the structure, that I then be able to search/ delete or print those names as I would any name that I add in via the program.

Comment: Seems you aren't incrementing your `counter` variable in your read function.

Comment: @Kludas Well that's what I thought originally, but when I add the `counter` it crashes the program.

Comment: You have `fr friends[5]` structures allocated in your array. Are you sure you aren't indexing out of bounds in that `fscanf` loop? Also, I noticed that's a lot of memory to allocate for a simple string. You had `#define BUFFSIZE 500`, so `500 * strlen(buffer)` would be 4000 bytes if you read in a 8 character lastname.

Comment: thought about that as well, and even tried changing it to `400` but still same results.

Comment: @Kludas I tried playing with those and manipulating them, still does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your read function to something like this where you pass in the size of your `friends` array so you don't read in too many lines and end up crashing your program. This is assuming you are reading in line by line from a text file.

This will loop while our `counter` is less than the number of elements in our `friends` array to ensure we don't go out of bounds while accessing each of the structures, OR if we reached the end of file, then it will stop.

To allocate memory for `Last_Name` we take the length of the string that got stored in `buffer` and add 1 to make room for the null terminating byte.

```
void file2(fr *friends, const size_t num_friends, FILE *read)
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    char buffer[128];

    while (counter < num_friends && fscanf(read, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {
        friends[counter].Last_Name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(friends[counter].Last_Name, buffer);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Then call this like `file2(friends, 5, read);` The middle argument is the size of your array.

`fscanf` can also overflow your `buffer` if you supply it with too much data. It has no bounds checking which can lead to crashing your program. I'd look into using `fgets` instead for next time.